# Transparent status and navigation bar in Flutter for both Android and IOS

Tags: flutter

I am making my first Flutter app and I have a question. I want to make the status bar and navigation bar transparent on both Android and IOS.
This is what I have now:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3DJ3.png

And this is what I want:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKrec.png

I am a beginner in Flutter so if you have a solution, please make it simple. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have updated the solution according to your gist. Check my answer please.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I know I am asking a lot of you but it still doesn't work. You don't have to, but maybe you can make a project as an example where it is working. Maybe I can see a difference in the code and change it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just replace your code with the one under `More details:`  in my answer, it works, I have just checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS you can not change color of the status bar according to their guidelines, though it is already transparent in iOS. For android, use it in the build method of your root widget:

```
if (Theme.of(context).platform == TargetPlatform.android) {
      SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
          SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.transparent));
    }
```

More details:

```
 import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show defaultTargetPlatform;
 Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Permission.camera.request();

  runApp(MyApp());
}


    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
    }
    
    class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
      @override
      void initState() {
        SchedulerBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
          if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
            SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
                SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.transparent));
          }
        });
        super.initState();
      }
    
      // This widget is the root of your application.
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: MyHomePage(),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for responding to my question. If I use this code in the main.dart file, I get a white status bar and black navigation bar.

Comment: Use it in the build method of your first widget (Top widget)

Comment: As mentioned before, I am a beginner in Flutter. I tried putting it in the code but I got an error. Could you help me with saying where I need to put the code? The dart file is availibe with this url: https://gist.github.com/StopmotionSimonYT/0861b37e39ec8ab9fa71c48ed21d8fe2
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What widget do you use in runApp() function?

Comment: Hello, thanks for helping me! I am not sure what you mean so I updated the Github Gist with the main.dart and other files.

Comment: Check my updated answer

Comment: Hello, I put the code in tabs.dart and webview.dart but it isn't working. What I see now is this: https://imgur.com/a/uYgCiF0 . I'm using API 32, maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: And again updated the answer. Check it

Comment: Changed Theme.of(context).platform to defaultTargetPlatform. Now it should work.

Comment: Hi, thanks for still thinking along with me. I have read your comment and have edited it. It is still the same as the picture in the previous comment.

Comment: Man, just replace your MyApp with the MyApp widget from my answer. I have just checked it - it works

Comment: DO NOT use it in Future<void> main. I converted your MyApp widget to stateful and used the changing color function in initState. Just copy and paste whole my code into your main.dart and try

Comment: Hi, still thanks for thinking along with me. You are right, the code you provided is working. But somehow in my project it's not working.

Comment: Provide your updated gist with main.dart please

Comment: Hi, I have uploaded my code in a Github repository which you can view with this link: https://github.com/StopmotionSimonYT/peppels_flutter_webview
The example code where your code is working is here: https://gist.github.com/StopmotionSimonYT/9a2906c2dd893e3f9ef4766620115143
Thanks for still thinking along with me.

Comment: Remove void main and MyApp from tabs.dart. And remove changing color function from initState of your MyHomePage

Comment: So there is what you need to do.

Comment: 1. Return everything in project as it was before. 2. just replace main.dart with my working code. And that's it

Comment: Did you try ? Did it work ?

Comment: Yes I tried it. At the first time it didn't work. After long searching I found why it was not working with a webview. Replacing `body: SafeArea` with `body: Container` was the solution. Thank you so much for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

You can set `color` or `backgroundColor` parameter to `Colors.transparent` as well.